# What could be the reason for "attribute layout_constraintstop_totopof not found" when I build my project in android studio? I am a beginner

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

I am designing a UI from a tutorial online.
The code doesn't underline any errors, the error pops up only when I try to build and test the app on my device.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your XML? So I'm able to help you with the constraints.

Comment: Oh! I see my problem Sir, it's " constraintTop" and not "constraintStop" like I mistakenly wrote. Notwithstanding, thanks for being there...

Comment: Sometimes it's that simple. You are welcome. For completeness I write it as an answer. Otherwise your question is empty.

Comment: Lol, that's funny. I answered 3 hours before Abubakar and he copies my answer and you tick his answer as the correct one? That's not fair, haha

Comment: haha big bro, Nevermind. Can't even tell why its so myself, but don't worry. On est ensemble... : ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need to use the right attribute sometimes android studio did not show you the suggestion therefore you need to know the lower and upper cases use in XML. Below is the code that will solve your problem.**

```
layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake:

`layout_constraintstop_totopof=""`
instead of `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf=""`